# BackgroundWorkers and SQL Connections

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

I'm hoping someone can offer some advice on what would be best practices when dealing with SQL connections in different threads.

The problem I'm experiencing now which make me ask the question (but I've been wondering about it for a while already) is as follows.

I have a dialog that requires a bit of time to initialise as it contains a control that is populated from a SQL database. It's not a massive query but it takes a couple of seconds and I figured there is no reason the user should wait those few seconds every time the dialog is shown or every time the form that contains the dialog is instantiated. So I put the code that populates the dialog in a `BackgroundWorker` so that it can happen in the background before the user even clicks on something that would show the dialog.

So far so good. Works lovely. Only problem, one of my forms (which makes use of this dialog) is itself populated by a SQL query, and moreover, it involves a slightly complex query (truncating a table and repopulating it), which I'd like to keep atomic so I put it all in a Transaction.

But now we have problems; By the time this Transaction is started the dialog has already been instantiated and its `BackgroundWorker` is already busy populating it. So I get an Exception that reads

> "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads
>   running in the session"

I can understand why I'd get an exception like this but I'm still unsure how best to address it.

But surely, this concept of having different queries run against the same DB in different threads, some of which may involve Transactions, can't be too uncommon. I reckon someone here must have been confronted by it before so I'm hoping someone can offer some advice.

*** EDIT ***
OK, here is some code to illustrate the problem. It would be overly complicated to provide the full code and my question is really about the principles of SQL Connections and multithreading more than it is about this particular problem I'm facing but I'll add this code anyway if it helps to understand the problem.

I have two forms, let's call them `Form_Main` and `Form_Dialog`. The latter is shown as a modal dialog when some button is clicked on the former. So their guts look something like this:

Form_Main.cs

```
public partial class Form_Main : Form
{
    public Form_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // The above function is automatically created by the IDE and is
        // defined in Form_Main.Designer.cs. It is inside this function
        // that the class of the dialog form is defined and instantiated
        // (and therefore its BackgroundWorker thread is started)

        Populate();
    }

    private void Populate()
    {
        using (SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = ClassGlobal.sqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(".....", ClassGlobal.sqlConnection, sqlTransaction))
            {
                // Here goes some code that populates the current
                // form, and it's encapsulated inside a Transaction
            }

            sqlTransaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (formDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        // Do some stuff with the return value from the dialog
    }
}
```

And Form_Dialog.cs

```
public partial class Form_Dialog : Form
{
    public Form_Dialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BackgroundWorker _populateWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _populateWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_populateWorker_DoWork);
        _populateWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void _populateWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(".....", ClassGlobal.sqlConnection, sqlTransaction))
        {
            // Here goes some code that populate the current form
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a snippet of ClassGlobal.cs

```
public sealed class ClassGlobal
{
    public static SqlConnection sqlConnection;

    static ClassGlobal()
    {
    }

    public static void DBInit(string server, string database, string uid, string password)
    {
        string connectionstring = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    }
}
```

`ClassGlobal` is instantiated early in the application and `DBInit` is called with the required connection parameters. All forms has access to the static `SQLConnection` which is defined in it.

As you can see from the above, looking at `Form_Main.cs`, by the time the `Populate()` function is called, the `InitializeComponent()` function had already been called so the constructor for `Form_Dialog` had also been called, so the `BackgroundWorker` of `Form_Dialog` is already churning away. For that reason, the Transaction inside `Form_Main`'s `Populate()` function can't be started.

Comment: Some example of some code that's not working as expected might be a good starting point. If you could try to produce a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) it would be appreciated.

Comment: You say its about SQL Connections but even with the code you've added, there's no sign of these connection objects? I'd have thought that if your question was *specifically* about connections we'd see some of them in the code.

Comment: OK, I've added some more code to show how the SQLConnection is used. Like I said though, I'm more interested in hearing general comments on best practices when it comes to multithreading database queries than a solution for this particular problem. In fact, I've already solved this particular problem (I'll post the solution below) but I'm not sure my approach to multithreading and DB queries in general is sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, okay, we can see the problem. Don't try to share `SqlConnection` objects. The only thing that should be shared and passed around is the connection *string*.

When you need a connection object, create a new one, `Open` it, use it, then `Dispose` of it. Let the connection pool (that works behind the scenes) take care of how many actual physical connections to the server are actually used.

So e.g.:

```
void _populateWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ClassGlobal.ConnectionString
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(".....", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        // Here goes some code that populate the current form
    }
}
```

and:

```
public sealed class ClassGlobal
{
    public static string ConnectionString;

    static ClassGlobal()
    {
    }

    public static void DBInit(string server, string database, string uid, string password)
    {
        ConnectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
    }
}
```

Comment: `ClassGlobal` should be `static` rather `sealed` as it stands atm.

Comment: Thanks Damien. This global SqlConnection has always bothered me but I was of the belief that it would be quicker than to establish a new connection with every new request. Didn't know about the connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new connection on every request, not have a static connection. The connection pool will take care of resource sharing (this is bad code, but should mean you don't need to make any changes elsewhere).

```
public sealed class ClassGlobal
{
    private static readonly string connectionstring;

    public static SqlConnection sqlConnection
    { 
       get 
       {
          return new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
       }
    }


    static ClassGlobal()
    {
    }

    public static void DBInit(string server, string database, string uid, string password)
    {
        connectionstring = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
    }
}
```